# animateNumber when you hit a certain scroll point | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, counter

Hi Guys I am relatively new to jQuery and am trying to create an infographic on a website. I want to make it count up to a number when you reach a certain scroll point on the page. I have used a plugin to animate the number from 0 to 14 when the page loads. However when I try to call the function at a certain scroll point it just loops. Therefore I believe I need a solution that stops it from looping. I have searched around and have come across .one() but this only seems to work with event handlers. Thanks for the help!

The Plugin i'm using:
https://github.com/aishek/jquery-animateNumber

Javascript:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {

var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

if (wScroll > $('.infographic').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2)) {

        $('#years').animateNumber({ 
            number: 14 
        },1500);
});
```

HTML:

```
<h2><span id="years">0</span></h2>
```

Comment: What do you mean it loops?

Comment: So it will count up to 14 and then restart when you scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the looping of animation (if that is what you meant) then keep a `flag` variable and set it to `true` initially now after animation, set it to `false`, and in the if condition check for the value of `check`

```
var check = true;

$(window).scroll(function () {

var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();

if (wScroll > $('.infographic').offset().top - ($(window).height() / 1.2) && check) {

        $('#years').animateNumber({ 
            number: 14 
        },1500);
        check = false;
});
```